# How can I use an Alias as function parameter, In PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, function, alias

I have an Alias named "github", for example.

```
Set-Alias -Name github -Value "C:\UserName\Folder\github"
```

Also I have a function named "goto", for example:

```
Function goto ( [string] alias ) { Set-Location -Path $alias }
```

How can I use this function on my terminal passing as parameter an alias.

```
> goto github
```

Output: `cannnot find "CurrentLocation\github" folder, cause the function not resolve the alias as parameter

Comment: `Set-Alias` is meant for a __function alias__ not to store aliases of strings. In fact, by simply trying out your alias you will get an error of an unrecognized cmdlet, function, script file or executable

Comment: Following JPBlanc now deleted answer, the simplest you can get around this is 2 functions and having your `goto` function receiving `$input`: `$function:goto = { Set-Location -Path $input }; $function:github = { 'path\to\something' }; github | goto`

Comment: You have all reason, `Set-Alias` is not my better solution, I should use `Global:variables` instead of `Set-Alias`

Comment: Can you post your answer explain why `Set-Alias` is not my better solution? I will mark this as my correct answer

Comment: IMO, a global variable is the most straightforward solution: `goto $github`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Alias, in simple terms, is just an **association to a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program**. When we [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.2), what's happening is that a new [`AliasInfo` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.aliasinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) is added to the `Alias:` PSDrive - See **[about Alias Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_alias_provider?view=powershell-7.2)** for details.

So, to recap, when we do:

```bash
Set-Alias -Name github -Value "C:\UserName\Folder\github"
```

What's actually happening is that the the alias with name **`github`** is being associated with what is expected to be a **command, cmdlet or function** but in this case is just a string containing a path.

A fun but useless demonstration:

```bash
PS /> Get-Alias github

CommandType     Name                                    Version    Source
-----------     ----                                    -------    ------
Alias           github -> C:\UserName\Folder\github

PS /> ${function:C:\UserName\Folder\github} = { 'hello' }
PS /> C:\UserName\Folder\github
hello

PS /> github
hello
```

---

An easy workaround for what you're looking for would be to have one function (`github`) that outputs a string containing the path you want to access and a second function (`goto`) that receives the pipeline input, for this we use a non-advanced function that leverages the [automatic variable `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input):

```bash
function goto { Set-Location -Path $input }
function github { 'path\to\something' }

github | goto
```

`Set-Alias` would also be a valid use case for [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) since this cmdlet already accepts values from pipeline:

```bash
Set-Alias -Name goto -Value Set-Location
function github { 'path\to\something' }

github | goto
```

Alternatively, [JPBlanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608772/jpblanc) suggested, in a now deleted answer:

```bash
function goto ([string] $alias) { Set-Location -Path $alias }   
function githubpath { "C:\UserName\Folder\github" }
```

Which would also work for a positional argument but **mandates the use of the [grouping operator `(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--)**:

```bash
goto (github)
```

#### Why ?

Without the grouping operator, the function `goto` would see `github` as an argument and **NOT as a separated function** which we want to invoke.

The operator forces the `github` function to be **invoked first** or, in other words, to **take precedence** and to produce it's output before the invocation of the `goto` function.

---

Another workaround would be to have just the `goto` function that has a definition with paths of interest in the form of a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2):

```
function goto {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory)] $Path)

    $map = @{
        github = "C:\UserName\Folder\github"
        foo    = "path\to\foo"
        bar    = "path\to\bar"
    }

    $map[$Path] | Set-Location
}

goto github
```