# how can i do a alias in powershell to start notepad++

Tags: powershell, notepad++, alias, notepad

How can I do a alias in powershell to start notepad++
have Start notepad++
and have alias i wanna combinate that

`set-alias -name notepad -value start notepad++`
but i get this error

Set-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'notepad++'.
At line:1 char:1

- set-alias -name notepad -value start notepad++
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Alias], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCommand
  ```

Comment: function Start-NotepadPlusPlus {
    Start-Process 'notepad++.exe' -ArgumentList @()
}
Set-Alias -Name notepad -Value Start-NotepadPlusPlus

Comment: `notepad++.exe` is already an executable application, why not just `Set-Alias -Name notepad -Value 'notepad++.exe'`?

Comment: Just tying in a few duplicates... https://stackoverflow.com/a/4167071 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70828654 https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000204 https://stackoverflow.com/a/72903166

Answer (score 1):

`Set-Alias` doesn't accept commands like that. You can do 1 of 2 things:

- Create a function that starts Notepad++; set an alias to that function. This is my perferred way so that I can go back to edit the function **without** editing the alias:

```
function Start-NotepadPlusPlus { 
    Start-Process 'notepad++.exe'
} 
Set-Alias -Name notepad -Value Start-NotepadPlusPlus
```

- Provide the path:

```
Set-Alias -Name notepad -Value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- Omit the `start` argument and provide the *full path* of `notepad++.exe` as the `-Value` argument, e.g. (if this full path doesn't work for you, see below for how to discover the correct one):

```bash
# Shorter alternative:
#    Set-Alias notepad $env:ProgramFiles\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
Set-Alias -Name notepad -Value $env:ProgramFiles\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

- Alternatively, if you want to rely on the convenience of `start` (`Start-Process`) being able to discover the location of `notepad++.exe` for you, you must use a *function* (`$args` passes any arguments through):

```bash
# PowerShell 7+
function notepad { start notepad++ $args }

# Windows PowerShell, to work around a bug.
function notepad { 
  $argsParam = if ($args) { @{ ArgumentList = $args } } else { @{} }
  start notepad++ @argsParam 
}
```

---

Building on the helpful comments:

- **In PowerShell, an alias is simply *another name* for a command** (which can be a PowerShell cmdlet, function, script, or external executable, and even another alias).

  - Therefore, **[`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias)'s `-Value` parameter only accepts a *single* argument** to describe the target of the name mapping.
  - `set-alias -name notepad -value start notepad++` is therefore *broken syntax*, because `notepad++` is an *extra* argument that `Set-Alias` doesn't recognize.
- **Since Notepad++ is a *GUI* program, there is no need to use `start` ([`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)) to launch it** *asynchronously*, i.e. without blocking the calling session, because *direct* invocation does that by default (see below for a *synchronous* solution).

  - Unfortunately, however, the Notepad++ installer does *not* include an entry in `$env:PATH` for its installation directory, hence the need to use `notepad.exe`'s *full path* above.
  - It does, however, create a *registry entry*, which allows `Start-Process` (as opposed to direct invocation) to discover `notepad++.exe`; if you want to rely on this for simplicity, you'll need to use a `function` rather than an alias, as described below (simply remove `-Wait` from the synchronous variant).
  - The simplest way to **discover `nodepad++.exe`'s full path** is to launch Notepad++ interactively with `Start-Process -PassThru` and access the `.Path` property of the process-information object that is returned:

    ```bash
    # -> 'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe', typically
    (Start-Process -PassThru notepad++).Path
    ```
- **In cases where you *do* need more than just another command's *name or path*** - typically when your "alias" should include *hard-coded arguments* to pass to the target command - you **must define a [`function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) instead**:

  - Here's a **variant of your "alias"** - **now of necessity implemented as a `function`** - that **uses `Start-Process -Wait` to launch Notepad++ *synchronously*, i.e. in a blocking fashion**, while also supporting pass-through arguments (which a true alias definition *implicitly* does).

    ```bash
    function notepad {
      if ($args) { # Pass-through arguments specified.
        Start-Process -Wait notepad++ $args
      } else {
        Start-Process -Wait notepad++
      }
    }
    ```

    - `notepad++` binds *positionally* to the `-FilePath` parameter, and `$args` to the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

      - Note the check for whether `$args` contains elements (`if ($args)`), which is - unfortunately - needed in *Windows PowerShell*, where a *bug* prevents passing an *empty* array to `-ArgumentList`; this problem has been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)
    - If your alias-like function also needs to support *pipeline input*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842481/45375).
    - For a more sophisticated but more complex way of wrapping other commands using so-called *proxy functions*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).